# ¿Es esto un error con el método math.random?

Tags: java

Hola tengo una duda con el siguiente código:

Os lo pongo las tres clases para ver si encontrais el fallo, puesto que soy novato y no se a que se debe (solo llevo 3 casi 4 meses).

```
public class Robot {

    private String recibirMensaje;
    private String contestarMensaje;

   private String Uno = "No necesito un príncipe, no soy la princesa que un machista relatador de cuentos vendió como débil e indefensa";
   private  String Dos = "Disculpa si te ofendí, mi intención era humillarte";
   private String Tres = "Que uno contemple el cielo de noche no lo convierte en astrónomo ¿sabes?";
   private   String Cuatro = "Creo que el brillo de mi teléfono me dejo ciega, porque no veo que me hables pendejo";
   private String Cinco = "No eres un viernes como para esperarte, ni un astronauta para darte espacio y mucho menos un concurso para darte una 2da oportunidad";

    private int base;
    private int exponente;
    private int resultadoP;

    private int n1;

    private int n2;

    public Robot (String recibirMensaje) {
        this.recibirMensaje = recibirMensaje;
    }

    public String getContestacion () {
        int random =  (int) Math.random() * 4;      
        switch (random) {
        case 1:

            contestarMensaje = Uno;
            break;

        case 2:
            contestarMensaje = Dos;
        break;

        case 3:
            contestarMensaje = Tres;
            break;

        case 4:
            contestarMensaje = Cuatro;
            break;

        case 5:
            contestarMensaje = Cinco;
            break;

        default: 
            break;
        }

        return contestarMensaje;
    }

    public void setPotencia (int base, int exponente) {

        this.base = base;

        this.exponente = exponente;

      }

    public String  getPotencia () {

    for (int i = 0; i < exponente; i++) {

       resultadoP = base * base;

       }

    return "SOY UN ROBOT MUY... LISTO HE HECHO ESTA POTENCIA  POR TI....-" + resultadoP;

    }

    public void setSumar (int n1, int n2) {

        this.n1 = n1;
        this.n2 = n2;

      }

    public String getSumar () {

        return "hOla HE ECHO ESTA SSSUMA QUE ME HAS PEDIDO, ADIOS HUMANO AHORA TIENES EL RESULTADO: " + (n1+n2) ;
    }

     public String getApagar () {

         return "APAaGANDO...";
      }
}
```

clase persona se encarga de darle ordenes a la otra clase robot:

```
public class PersonaChateaConRobot {



    private String enviarMensaje;

    private String recibirRobot;

    private String decirOrdenes;

    public PersonaChateaConRobot  (String enviarMensaje) {

        this.enviarMensaje = enviarMensaje;
    }


    public void setMensajeRobot (String recibirRobot) {

        this.recibirRobot = recibirRobot;

    }

    public void getOrdenes (String decirOrdenes) {

        this.decirOrdenes = decirOrdenes;

    }
}
```

Clase con método main:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class mainRobot {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String mensajeDePersona = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Bienvenido al sistema para hablar con un robot online, introuduzca su pregunta");

        PersonaChateaConRobot persona = new PersonaChateaConRobot (mensajeDePersona);

        Robot robot = new Robot (mensajeDePersona);

        System.out.println("Cita:" + " ' " + mensajeDePersona + " ' ");

        System.out.println(robot.getContestacion());
    }

}
```

Salida por pantalla:

```
Cita: ' hola que tal ' 

null
```

¿A que se debe que ni me devuelva el valor de recibir Mensaje¿ ¿Estoy haciendo algo mal con el método Math.Random o  con el switch? Creo que   el   problema  es  con el método   Math. Random pero no estoy seguro. ¡ayuda!

Postdata: No hagáis caso a las frases las he cogido de una pagina web así a lo ràpido.

Comment: Por favor evita el uso de mayúsculas sostenidas en el título de tu pregunta, del mismo modo sería mucho mejor que agregues el mensaje del error al título de la misma

Comment: @BetaM ok la proxima vex intentare mejorarlo.

Comment: Al parecer si tiene que ver con la el método Random utilizado, revise este enlace http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=Generar_n%C3%BAmeros_aleatorios_en_Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El uso de random no es el adecuado para el intervalo que buscas. No te da siempre un entero, no siempre está en el intervalo que supones.

Para obtener un pseudoaleatorio entero debe ser:

`(int)(Math.random() * range) + min;`

Donde `min` es el valor mínimo del intervalo (en tu caso es 1) y `range` es `(max - min) + 1` (se le suma 1 para decir que el rango incluye el número final).

Podrías seguir la recomendación de esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7961881/236345) y usar una función así:

```
int randomWithRange(int min, int max)
{
   int range = (max - min) + 1;     
   return (int)(Math.random() * range) + min;
}
```

Le das los valores mínimo y máximo cada vez y tendrás un valor entero que servirá para seleccionar tu frase mágica.